# Overflow: hidden not being filled 100% by psuedo element?

Tags: html, css

It's hard to explain this. I'm trying to do something like this:
https://codepen.io/pen/yLBaJOq

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 9px solid black;
    border-radius: 55px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.button:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-30deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    width: calc(100% + 30px);
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 0%;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
}


.button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: 9px solid red;
}

.button:hover:before {
    padding-top: 200%;
}
```

But there's a thin line between the border and the element. Like the pseudo-element :before is not filling out the parent 100%. Image of what I mean:
[image: Image of button hover]

It's happening in all browsers I'm trying (Chrome, FF, Safari, all Mac).
So I'm wondering if I can prevent this from happening, while still keeping a similar hover effect.

I could of course just use the transition on the background color and scrap the idea with the pseudo-element as the background.

Answer (score 0):

Add background color to the button hover.

Change:

```
.button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: 9px solid red;
}
```

to:

```
.button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: 9px solid red;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 9px solid black;
    border-radius: 55px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.button:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-30deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 0%;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 9px solid red;
  background: red;
}

.button:hover:before {
  padding-top: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">WOAH</div>
```